# Laravel4 Carbon loop through week

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to loop trough the current week with carbon and display every single day in the view.

$current_mon and $current_sun is a dropdown to select the current week from monday to sunday. 
I have no idea how to get the rest of the week (tue to sat) as

```
    $tues = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->addDay();
```

is a bad idea!

My Controller is:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
    $current_mon = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();        
    $current_sun = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('d-M');
    $tues = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->addDay(); 
    return View::make('backend/menubuilder/edit')->with('id',$id)->withCurrent_mon($current_mon)->withCurrent_sun($current_sun)->withTues($tues);
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod`.

**Controller:**

```
$startDate = \Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();        
$endDate = \Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
//Init interval
$dateInterval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
//Init Date Period from start date to end date
//1 day is added to end date since date period ends before end date. See first comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php
$datePeriod = new \DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate->modify('+1 day'));

return View::make('backend/menubuilder/edit',[$datePeriod]);
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($datePeriod as $datePeriodRow)
    {!! DateTime Object: See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php !!}
    {{$datePeriodRow->format('d-M')}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Right now I get 8 days in my view, as there is 1 day also added to $endDate. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: At the line `$datePeriod`... switch from `$endDate->modify('+1 day') to `$endDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Mysterious answer I got it:

Controller

```
$startDate = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
    $endDate = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
    //Init interval
    $dateInterval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    //Init Date Period from start date to end date
    //1 day is added to end date since date period ends before end date. See first comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php
    $dateperiod = new \DatePeriod($startDate, $dateInterval, $endDate);

    return View::make('backend/menubuilder/edit')->with('id',$id)->withDateperiod($dateperiod);
```

this displays the entire current week from monday to sunday
Thanks again

Comment: Tip: pass your data directly in the `View::make()` function. Using `->with()` will get tiresome if you have more than 10 variables to pass around.